# bash sed causing error in serialized array

Tags: php, bash, ssh, sed

I have just switched a .com over from a .co.uk and everything went great until today. I ran SQL to replace the domain in all relevant tables, and I used `sed` to do the same in all relevant php files on the server, after using cp to move the files to the .com folder.

All is well, except for one little aspect. One of the files I used `sed` on is a serialized php array, and now php throws `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 326 of 1551099 bytes in reallylongfilename.php on line` when I try to unserialize it.

I have just tested the file from the old server before sed, and it unserializes no problem, but then I ran sed and it fails. The sed command I am using is:

```
sudo find /var/www/vhosts/spotthedog.com/httpdocs/wp-content/feedgenerator -name 'propdetails.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/spotthedog.co.uk/spotthedog.com/g' {} \;
```

I am fairly new to working on the command line, so any help gratefully received as I am considering writing a php script to do the same job.

Comment: Without access to the actual offending code, this is pretty much impossible to diagnose. You aren't escaping dots so it's a fair guess that some actual program code statements happen to contain "co" and "uk" with onr character between them.

Comment: what ist he content of `reallylongfilename.php`? does it contain **serialized data** or there are PHP codes also? is it a data file or PHP file?

Answer (score 4):

**Serialized data looks like string because we can read it. But its not string at all.** `serialize()` **stores the length of string** for string type data.

```
php > echo serialize("spotthedog.com");
s:14:"spotthedog.com";
php > echo serialize("spotthedog.co.uk");
s:16:"spotthedog.co.uk";
php >
```

You are replacing the string, but NOT the length. Hence the error. You should not perform string operations (e.g. replace) on data that is not string.

You better unserialize them first. Then use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export)/[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to export them. and run `sed` on it.

Another hacky option would be using [`array_map_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#107808) in the file where it gets unserialized. Call it to replace all the domain names

```
function array_map_recursive($fn, $arr) {
    $rarr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $rarr[$k] = is_array($v)
            ? array_map_recursive($fn, $v)
            : $fn($v); // or call_user_func($fn, $v)
    }
    return $rarr;
}

$arr = array_walk_recursive(function($val){
    return is_string($val)? 
            str_replace("spotthedog.com", "spotthedog.co.uk", $val): $val;
}, $arr);
```

Comment: Thanks. I love PHPs array functions, but I was hoping to do this the quick way on the command line. One command copies the files from .co.uk to .com and then the next does the replacement. I am writing the php script to do the unserialize, replace and then serialize now

Comment: `I am writing the php script to do the unserialize, replace and then serialize now`. Thats correct way to solve it. You can not perform string operations on packed data which looks like string but they are not. Try using json_encode next time.

Answer (score -1):

Revert your serialized file back to the backup version, unserialize it, change domain manually and reserialize.

Alternatively, modify the serialized variable yourself. To do it, all you have to do is find the place where .com is mentioned and lower the s:**SOME_NUMBER**:" before that string by 2 (so if it was 16, it should be 14, etc.) as .co.uk is 2 characters longer than .com

Comment: I am afraid it is more than one file, but all are the same kind of data. I am sure that sed can be used to do this, it just needs tweaking by someone more experienced in it than i

Comment: You'll have to match the number after s:, with something like this: s:([0-9]+):" and subtract 2 from it in your replacement.